# How to cancel Android ListView item from being activated/highlighted in ListView's setOnItemClickListener?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

In one of my Activities, I have multiple **ListView** controls. Say **List 1**, **List 2** & **List 3**. On **List 1** item's click, i load data for **List 2** & **List 3** from a webservice. And the clicked item's background is highlighted. I achieved this through following selector.

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_focused" android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected"/>
```

As you can see, i have specified the **android:state_activated="true"** to change the BG of the clicked/tapped item. This works well.

Actually i want to prevent the clicked item from being selected/highlighted if data for some other item is being loaded ... like

```
list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                // load data if no other call to web service is in progress
                if (_isNotLoadingData) {
                     loadList2AndList3DataUsingWebService();
                } else {
                    //Stop This Item From selected/highlighted
                    //BUT none of the following work. .. Item is always Selected
                    view.setSelected(false);
                    //view.setActivated(false);
                    //view.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Above code stops multiple calls to be directed to our web service but i am unable to stop the item from being highlighted/activated if the web service is not called for that ListView item.

How can i acieve this?

**EDIT on 8:08 pm 19 Mar, 2012:** No proper reply yet ... i am stuck & waiting for any help

Comment: Why do you want to cancel the click?

Comment: Why you dont just make a if statement into your onItemClick method? If it is the first thing in your onItemClick function then it is basically same like a onBeforeClick() function...

Comment: i have updated my question & explained. Sorry for providing an unclear question

Comment: @AamirHabib You have to add `.setItemSelected()` to the parent ListView, not to the child. See my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I actually encountered the same issue a few days ago. The solution is *not* to set view.setItemChecked(false), but instead in the `.onItemClick()`-method, call your *listview* and set `listview.setItemChecked(position, false)`. This solved it for me.

Example:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            int position, long arg3) {

        // load data if no other call to web service is in progress
        if (_isNotLoadingData) {
             loadList2AndList3DataUsingWebService();

        } else {
            ListView lv = (ListView) adapterView;
            lv.setItemChecked(position, false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: tough i have fixed the problem by some other work around ... but if i had not used that solution ... i would have preferred urs way... i will mark ur comment as answer

Comment: Dude thanks for the approach. Is there anyway you still maintain the "select" behavior and disable only the "activated" behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Make the item in the adapter disabled. This will remove all clicks while you don't have to disable the item click listener or other such hacks.

I don't know how your adapter looks, but generally you override some methods in your adapter. Note that I call the method isLocked instead of isNotLocked. Using negative boolean values is generally a bad idea that causes confusion and in this case you won't even have to set it to false at the start since this is the default value for boolean.

```
public class MyCoolAdapter extends ListAdapter {

private boolean mIsLocked;

public boolean areAllItemsEnabled () {
    return false;
}

public abstract boolean isEnabled (int position) {
    if (mIsLocked) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
...
}
```

If you want to disable just certain rows you return false for those positions and true for others.

You will have to notify that dataset has changed when you change the isLoading parameter. This will cause the listview to requery the adapter.
For example:

```
public void setIsLoading(final boolean isLocked) {
   mIsLocked = isLocked;
   notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

within the onclick listener you can call setonclicklistener(null) on the view that call the click event. That way view will remove its own onclicklistener.

```
mTitleView.setOnClickListener(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting list selector to null using [setSelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setSelector%28int%29).

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to handle click event after first click, just use `yourList.setOnItemClickListener(null)`

Comment: @AamirHabib wouldnt it be a better idea to prevent your users from clicking other items (the way this answer suggests) rather than just disabling the highlight? That way your users would know for sure that the particular list entry is not available for action at the moment.

Comment: i already had done it the same way ... by disabling the entire list for two a few seconds when an item is clicked with aim that web service response would have received during these few seconds ... but i was looking for something like @Reinier suggested ... i may be wrong .. but that stuff worked as i planned

Answer (score -1):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
                int position, long arg3)
        {

            //view.setEnabled(false);
            //adapterView.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });
```

1. view.setEnabled(false); Use this if you want to disable the listItem which user has clicked.Thus prevents the onclick event on that particular item.
2. adapterView.setEnabled(false); Use this if you want to disable the entire listView.
   It will prevent onclick event on entire listView.

Hope this help

Comment: thanks for your answer .. but this does not work ... i tried using **view.setSelected(false)** too but not worked. ... Actually i want to prevent the clicked item from being selected/highlighted if data for some other item is being loaded .. i also updated my question